# Manipulation on Pivot in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, pivot, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Pivot with 2 PivotItems. I'm trying to detect whether the user swiped left or right. I thought I could detect this by checking the difference between the ManipulationStarted and ManipulationCompleted point. But whatever I do, those events won't get triggered.

```
<Pivot x:Name="albumart_pivot" Margin="0,-30,0,0" ManipulationStarted="ManipulationStartedEvent" ManipulationCompleted="ManipulationCompletedEvent" ManipulationMode="TranslateX">
    <PivotItem Margin="0">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="1" Fill="White" Opacity="0.1" Margin="20"/>
            <Image x:Name="albumart0" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Source="{Binding albumart}" Margin="20" Height="{Binding screenwidth}" Width="{Binding screenwidth}" ManipulationStarted="albumart_pivot_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="albumart_pivot_ManipulationCompleted"/>
        </Grid>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Margin="0">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="1" Fill="White" Opacity="0.1" Margin="20"/>
            <Image x:Name="albumart1" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Source="{Binding albumart}" Margin="20" Height="{Binding screenwidth}" Width="{Binding screenwidth}" ManipulationStarted="albumart_pivot_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="albumart_pivot_ManipulationCompleted"/>
        </Grid>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

I also tried with detecting Pointer. The PointerEntered event does get fired, but the PointerExited/PointerReleased/PointerCanceled don't...

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Like [yasen had said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043683/2681948) - Pivot intercepts touch events. I think one of the solutions may be to disable your Pivot and make use of a Grid's `ManipulationCompleted` event (in witch you will have to change PivotItems manually):

In XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Pivot Name="myPivot">
        <PivotItem Header="One"/>
        <PivotItem Header="Two"/>
        <PivotItem Header="Three"/>                
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

In code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    myPivot.IsHitTestVisible = false; // disable the Pivot 
    LayoutRoot.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX;
    LayoutRoot.ManipulationCompleted+=LayoutRoot_ManipulationCompleted;
}

private void LayoutRoot_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var velocity = e.Velocities;
    if (velocity.Linear.X < 0) // swipe to the left
    {
        if (myPivot.SelectedIndex < myPivot.Items.Count - 1) myPivot.SelectedIndex++;
        else myPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    else if (myPivot.SelectedIndex > 0) myPivot.SelectedIndex--; // to the right
    else myPivot.SelectedIndex = myPivot.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, although the Pivot won't move with the swipe realtime. I know this is solvable by using ManipulationDelta. I just wanted to know if there was an easy solution. Since there is none, I guess I'll change my logic so I can use three pivotitems (so I can use SelectionChanged). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The events you're talking about are handled by the Pivot itself, so it might be tricky to catch them yourself.

Maybe you can use the Pivot's SelectionChanged event? Or maybe the Loading/Loaded/Unloading/UnloadedPivotItem events?

Comment: I think the best way is to find a way to work with 3 pivotitems then, so I can use the SelectionChanged event..

Comment: @PhilippeMaes May I ask what are you trying to achieve? What do you want to do when you detect the swipe?

Comment: I'm implementing the ability to skip to to next and previous song by swiping the albumart (which is in a pivot).

Comment: @PhilippeMaes Do you want to change the PivotItem when the user swipes? If not, that's not a good idea. It will be bad UX, as people swiping over a Pivot expect to change the PivotItem.

Comment: PivotItem will change when user swipes :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the late answer.

You are right some system controls of WP 8.X, intercept touch events. The cause is the performance optimization of the system controls and improvement of the user experience.
But the OS provides a way to control this behavior by the [UseOptimizedManipulationRouting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/system.windows.frameworkelement.useoptimizedmanipulationrouting.aspx) property of the FrameworkElement.