# swipe left or right in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am looking to understand gesture or horizontal swipe event in windows phone 8.1. I have below code which works fine but don't how to understand the status of swipe. Whether it is right swipe or left swipe. So my question is How to identify swipe right and left?

```
void MainPage_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ps = e.GetIntermediatePoints(null);
            if (ps != null && ps.Count > 0)
            {
                gr.ProcessUpEvent(ps[0]);
                e.Handled = true;
                gr.CompleteGesture();
            }
        }
        void gr_CrossSliding(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlidingEventArgs args)
        {
            //How to know you swipe left and right

        }
        void MainPage_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            gr.ProcessMoveEvents(e.GetIntermediatePoints(null));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        void MainPage_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ps = e.GetIntermediatePoints(null);
            if (ps != null && ps.Count > 0)
            {
                gr.ProcessDownEvent(ps[0]);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

And my constructor

```
Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlideThresholds cst = new Windows.UI.Input.CrossSlideThresholds();
cst.SelectionStart = 2;
cst.SpeedBumpStart = 3;
cst.SpeedBumpEnd = 4;
cst.RearrangeStart = 5;
gr.CrossSlideHorizontally = true;
gr.CrossSlideThresholds = cst;
gr.CrossSliding += gr_CrossSliding;

gr.GestureSettings = GestureSettings.CrossSlide;
```

Comment: Maybe you can remember where was the first point pressed and then, upon release, check relesed position and compare with the rememered one.

Comment: That was an idea, Don't know if this serves as a solution here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to remember where was the first point pressed and then, upon release, check relesed position and compare with the rememered one. This should allow to idetify in which direction user has moved his finger.

Also if it would be possible, you can also think of using *Velocities* when using *manipulation* events - [example at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043826/2681948).